# Keras Xception trained from scratch give ~100% accuracy in the history but only predicts 1 when evaluating, giving 50% accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm training an Xception model on keras without using pre-trained weights for a Binary Classification problem, and I get a very strange behavior. The history plot shows that the training accuracy is increasing until it touch 100%, while the validation one is always around 50%, so it seems it's overfitting but that's not the case, since I checked and it always predict (close to) 1 even on the training set.

What could be the reason of this behaviour?

Here is the code I'm using to train. `x_train_xception` has already been preprocessed by the `keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input` function.

I'm using the same code, except the model creation, for training a pretrained Xception model, which works fine

```
inLayerX = Input((512, 512, 4))
xceptionModel = keras.applications.Xception(include_top = True, weights=None, input_tensor=inLayerX, classes=1, classifier_activation= 'sigmoid')

xceptionModel.compile(loss= 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = xceptionModel.fit(x_train_xception, y_train, batch_size= batch_size, epochs= epochs, validation_data=(x_val_xception, y_val))

_, accTest = xceptionModel.evaluate(x_test_xception, y_test)
_, accVal = xceptionModel.evaluate(x_val_xception, y_val)
_, accTrain = xceptionModel.evaluate(x_train_xception, y_train)
print("Training accuracy {:.2%}".format(accTrain))
print("Validation accuracy {:.2%}".format(accVal))
print("Test accuracy {:.2%}".format(accTest))
```

which output:

```
2/2 [==============================] - 6s 2s/step - loss: 1.2063 - accuracy: 0.5000
1/1 [==============================] - 4s 4s/step - loss: 1.2960 - accuracy: 0.4667
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 1.2025 - accuracy: 0.5083
Training accuracy 50.83%
Validation accuracy 46.67%
Test accuracy 50.00%
```

the validation and test accuracy is expected but what's bugging me is really the training accuracy, which I would expect to be close to 100% looking at the history.
[Model Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL22f.png)
[Model Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQIHT.png)

Comment: What is the reason for not using any optimizer for model compilation?

Comment: I don't really know what the difference between one and another are, so I use the default one.

Comment: The optimizer is required, because it will help the model to learn from the given data and calculated loss, thus will also increase the accuracy.